# How to use $.when for a callback function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to say when this function close() is finished run this function init(). But it's not working for me.

```
$.when(close(toolTip)).done(init(toolTip, anchor));
```

I am not using the $.when for anything ajax related, just trying to make sure close() is finished before I call init(), and no I can't stick init() at the end of close().  Any ideas?

ok here is close()

```
var close = function (toolTip) {
    toolTip.fadeOut('fast', function (e) {
        if (typeof e !== 'undefined') {
            //Re-set values applied when initted
            var toolTipBd = toolTip.find('.bd:first');
            toolTip.css('width', '');
            toolTipBd.css('max-height', '');
            toolTip.css('max-height', '');
            toolTipBd.css('overflowY', '');
        }
    });
};
```

No where in close() can it call init().

Comment: Is close(toolTip) performing some asynchronous function? If so, does that function have a callback?

Comment: We would need to see what `close()` is doing, it must return a promise or deferred object to be used with `$.when`, and your call to `init()` is wrong unless it returns a function.

Answer (score 1):

Your `close()` implementation should be like this:

```
var close = function (toolTip) {
    var d = $.Deferred();

    toolTip.fadeOut('fast', function (e) {
        if (typeof e !== 'undefined') {
            //Re-set values applied when initted
            var toolTipBd = toolTip.find('.bd:first');
            toolTip.css('width', '');
            toolTipBd.css('max-height', '');
            toolTip.css('max-height', '');
            toolTipBd.css('overflowY', '');
        }

        d.resolve();
    });

    return d.promise();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`$.when` works with [`Deferred`'s](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred). It returns a new `Deferred` which will resolve when all the `Deferred`'s you provided resolve.

As `close()` doesn't seem to be returning a Promise, `when` will resolve straight away (per the [docs for `when()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when).

However, if `close()` is synchronous, you don't need `when()` at all. If it *is* asynchronous, you need to return a `Promise`, and resolve it when your animation or whatever has completed;

```
function close(what) {
    var promise = jQuery.Deferred();

    what.fadeOut('slow', function () {
        promise.resolve();
    });

    return promise.promise();
}
```

... but you still don't need `$.when` as only **1** promise is involved. `$.when` is only useful when multiple promises are at play.

```
close(toolTip).done(function () {
    init(toolTip, anchor);
});
```

Note also that `done(init(tooltip, anchor))` will call `init` immediately, and pass the *result* of that function invocation to `done()`; instead, you need to pass a *function* to done. As `init` needs parameters, we've fixed this by introducing an anonymous function. If `init` didn't need any parameters, it'd have been as simple as:

```
close(toolTip).done(init);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply return toolTip:

```
return toolTip.fadeOut(...
```

using the callback to resolve a deferred object can result in odd results if there are more than one elements selected for whatever reason.

This works because jQuery objects have a `.promise` method that when called, return a promise object that resolves when all active animations are completed. `$.when` calls `.promise` on all passed in arguments.

You'll also need to call init differently, for example,

```
$.when(close(toolTip)).done(function(){
    init(toolTip, anchor);
});
```

And, as pointed out by others, you could then shorten that to

```
close(toolTip).promise().done(function(){
    init(toolTip, anchor);
});
```